# Array property in objects

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to have an array for the property in objects?

```
var x = { [100, 200]: [a,b,c], [100, 300]: [a,b,c], [200, 300]: [a,b,c] }
```

What I'm trying to do is if the property array doesn't exist, add a new spot to the object. The above line doesn't work, so whats the correct way to structure this?

I want to use the object to print out to look like:

100 200 a b c

100 300 a b c

200 300 a b c

Comment: please add a valid object.

Comment: Nope, but if the print result is the only goal, you can do this: `{'100 200': [a, b, c], ... , '200 300': [a, b, c]}`, the arrays are usually printed with commas, though. Also you can't have multiple same property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Map` Object, which allows for anything to be a key. In order to retrieve by key you can use `Map.get` and to add a value(outside of declaration) you can use `Map.set` - the caveat with using an array as a key is that it is a referential data type. It is a pointer to the data, not the data itself. This means that you must store the variable before using it as a key whether for getting or setting. As an example

```
let a = [1,2,3];
Map.set(a, "test");
Map.get(a); // test
```

will work, however

```
Map.set([1,2,3], "test");
Map.get([1,2,3]); // undefined
```

will not work.

Example of Declaration with your current data set:

```js
var x = new Map( [ [[100, 200], ["a","b","c"]], [[100, 300], ["a","b","c"]], [[200, 300], ["a","b","c"]] ]);


x.forEach((value, key, map) => {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
});
```

Get Example:

```js
let x = new Map(), a = [3,4,5];

x.set([1,2,3], "example");
console.log( x.get([1,2,3]) );
// will not work because an array is a referential data type

x.set(a, "other example");
console.log(x.get(a));
// will work because your array is a variable.
```

Comment: Would there be a way to combine similar keys values? So if i had `[[100,200], [2,3]],[[100,200],[4,5]],[[100,300],[1,2]]` it would show to be `[[100,200],[6,8]],[[100,300],[1,2]]`?

Comment: @Qaqiaq I'm sure there is but that's an entirely separate question, I would suggest giving it a try and then asking if you're having trouble. I do have to say that my advice would be to rethink your data structure. What you're doing seems to be incredibly messy and ill advised, both for maintenance and readability's sake.